# read a column from a file, increase each element by a constant, then rewrite back to file in bash

Tags: bash

I tried to read a column from a file, increase each element by a constant, then rewrite back to file in bash. For example, the column is

```
1  
2  
3  
4
```

I want to rewrite them back as

```
5  
6  
7  
8
```

I tried the following, it works. I am wondering if there are simpler ways without for loop in bash.

```
n=( $(awk '{print $1}' ./test) )  
len=${#n[*]}   

for (( i=0; i<=$(( $len -1 )); i++ ))  
do  
    n[$i]=$((${n[$i]} + 2000))  
done  
echo ${n[*]} > test2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example, you are increasing by 4. It can be easily done in awk like this.

```
awk '{print $1 + 2000}'  < test > test2
```

Demo:

```
$ echo "1  
2  
3  
4 "  | awk '{print $1 + 4}' 
5
6
7
8
$
```

Comment: I'm assuming the O.P. is a newbie, so I'll warn do not be tempted to do `awk '...prog...' file > file` you will wipe out your original file and wonder what happened to your data.. One solution is `awk '...prog...' file > newFile && mv newFile file` where the `mv` command will only execute it the `awk` command finished successfully. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you. I missed the part of changing data in same file.

Answer (score 1):

You can try a while read loop, Using a pure shell solution.

```
constant=4
while read -r line; do
  printf '%d\n' $((line + constant))
done < <(awk '{print $1}' file.txt ) > out.txt
```

The shell can process the first column without `awk` by saving each line in an array which requires using the `-a` flag/option to `read`

```
constant=4
while read -ra line; do
   printf '%d\n' $((line + constant))
done <  file.txt > out.txt
```

- `"$line"` is the same as `${line[0]}"` which is the first element in an array.
- The `$` can be omitted inside the arithmetic/math context inside `$(( ))`

Or just by doing a Parameter expansion.

```
constant=4
while read -r line; do
  printf '%d\n' $((${line%%[[:space:]]*} + constant))
done <  file.txt > out.txt
```

---

EDIT: 
   As suggested by ogus ismail, the builtin `read` can have a dummy variable which can hold the rest of the columns/fields, (since we are after just the first field/column) which is a `_` .

```
constant=4
while read -r column1 _ ; do
  printf '%d\n' $((column1 + constant))
done <  file.txt > out.txt
```

- See [Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html)
- See [Shell Arithmetic](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Arithmetic.html#Shell-Arithmetic)
- See [Shell looping construct](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Looping-Constructs.html)
- See [Bash builtins](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html#Bash-Builtins) and look for `printf` and `read`

Comment: @oguzismail, right I totally forgot about that, will add it in the post.